# Having trouble scraping data from website with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I've tried a couple different routes to get this to work but I've had no luck.

1)

```
driver= webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\Users\x\Downloads\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')
driver.get('https://www.drf.com/race-results')

elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='handicappingBottom']")
```

for item in elements:
    print(item)

*Returns an empty list

I then read up a bit and feel like the webpage isn't fully loading those items so I tried multiple variants of this:

```
elements = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 45).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "handicappingBottom")))
```

[image: Example of code snippet from webpage:]

Ideally I'm trying to scrape the current horse race locations into a list in a program I'm mocking up. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. I'm new-ish to python and even newer than that to webscraping. Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: Welcome. Well, Selenium is one option, but the tool is not designed for web scrapping. I'd probably go for sth. like [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). It might be faster as well as designed for this very purpose, therefore offering better ways for web scrapping.

Comment: Will look into this - thank you for the recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am not sure why you are printing that

try the below code if you want to get the displayed text from those elements:

```
value= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='handicappingBottom']").get_attribute('textContent');

print(value);
```

if this doesn't work, then try in your code:

```
for item in elements: print(item.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

I made it working using protractor:

[image]

If you just need any tool for achieving this, then you could use protractor:

**Steps to use protractor:**

1. Install nodejs first, it will install npm along with it which is
   like pip for nodejs : https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. now install protractor:

> `npm install -g protractor`

4. Now create a file called conf.js and add the below code in it and save

> ```
>  exports.config = {
>
> specs: ['test.js'],
>
> capabilities: {
>   'browserName': 'chrome',
> },
>
> onPrepare: function(){
>     browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
>     browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
> },
>
>   jasmineNodeOpts: {
>     showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
>     defaultTimeoutInterval: 10000000,
>
> },
> SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
> }
> ```

5. Now create a file test.js and copy-paste below code in it :

> ```
> describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
> it('should have a title @Regression @Smoke @test', async   function() {
>     await browser.get('https://www.drf.com/race-results');
>     let a=await element.all(by.xpath('//div[@class="handicappingBottom"]')).getAttribute('textContent');
>     console.log(a);
>   });
>   });
> ```

5. Keep both conf.js and test.js in the same folder and run below command in cmd:

> `protractor conf.js`